# Convert Activity into a Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I am new at Android and I'm trying to turn this `Activity` into a `Fragment` but I do not know how to resolve the Errors.

When I change it to a `Fragment` I get a lot of red code `setContentView`, `findViewById`, and `getMenuInflater`. I understand that these are probably red as they are meant to be used for `Activities` but I'm not sure what they are meant to be changed to.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class LocationsFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_demo);
        // Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView =
                (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_card_demo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Fragment tutorials on https://d.android.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## setContentView()

There is no method like this in Fragments. Instead, you override `onCreateView()` and return some view from it. You can use the passed-in `LayoutInflater` to inflate the layout id you'd normally pass to `setContentView()`, and then return that.

## findViewById()

Fragments do not have a `findViewById()` method. However, any time after `onCreateView()` returns, you can instead use `getView().findViewById()`. Inside `onCreateView()`, if you named your inflated view `root` you could call `root.findViewById()`. Prior to `onCreateView()`, there's no way to look up any views (since they haven't been inflated yet).

## getMenuInflater()

Fragments use a different signature for `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. It looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // ...
}
```

You can use the passed-in `MenuInflater` instead of calling `getMenuInflater()`.

---

Put that all together, and this is what you'd have:

```
public class LocationsFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_demo, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_card_demo, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also beware that for the fragment options menu to work, you have to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.